# How to get sorting without removing Row-Created function(Use for changing column of header-text in run-time)

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code is my Grid View AA from aspx page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_AA" runat="server" OnSorting = "Gridview_AA_Sorting" OnRowCreated="GridView_AA_RowCreated">
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Period Name" SortExpression="PERIOD_NAME">
 <EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtGVPeriodName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PERIOD_NAME") %>'></asp:TextBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblGVPeriodName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PERIOD_NAME") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lborganize" runat="server" OnClick="lborganize_Click" Text='<%# Bind("PERIOD_NAME") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="400px" />
 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="400px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

I cannot sort after adding GridView_AA_RowCreated function. Each column of Grid view header-text worked well before I add this Row Created function. If I cut the following code: e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Period Name";
Sorting works. I want to get sorting without removing this Row Created function. Do you have any brighter solution about my problem?

```
 protected void GridView_AA_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
           {
                    e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Period Name"; //Change header text in run-time
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The above problem is solved after I changed the following code into the Row Created function:

```
protected void GridView_AA_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                LinkButton lb_pname = (LinkButton)(e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0]);
                lb_pname.Text = "Period Nameะ";
                e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(lb_pname);
            }
}
```